# Use Application Permissions to access an Inbox?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I tried finding this scenario in the Microsoft Graph documentation, but I never found one.

I am trying to use Microsoft Graph Client for .Net in my C# console application. The application needs to open an Inbox without a user signing in and download the emails so that it can process them.

I first tried MSAL with Application Authentication, but I could never get a token back.  So, I took a try at using OAuth and ADAL and it seems like I am getting tokens and getting access to the graph.

But, I am logged in as an application... so, there is no user and therefore no inbox.  I tried to lookup the user mailbox, but I get an authentication error.  This makes sense to me because there is no place to enter the inbox credentials.

Does anyone know how to get a Daemon app to get access to a mailbox?

If you go the [permissions scopes documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference) under Mail, it only shows `Delegate` permissions.  So, does that mean a console app cannot access a mailbox?  Or, can I log into a mailbox using `Delegate` but not have a login popup box?

I think I am also confused between the ApplicationId, the Mailbox name(something like `myuser@microsoft.com`), and the AD user (ex. `myuser_IT`)

Here's my code:

```cs
class AuthenticationHelper : IAuthenticationProvider
{
    public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        string clientId = "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx";
        string clientSecret = "yyYYyyYY"; //this is a secret.

        try
        {
            AuthenticationContext authContext =
                new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token");

            ClientCredential creds = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

            AuthenticationResult authResult =
                await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", creds);

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authResult.AccessToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

public class InboxProcessor
{
    public async Task DownloadEmails(string inbox)
    {
        try
        {
            IMailFolderMessagesCollectionPage inboxMessages = null;

            GraphServiceClient graphClient =
                new GraphServiceClient(new AuthenticationHelper());

            User myUser = await graphClient
                .Users[inbox]
                .Request()
                .GetAsync(); //this give a permission error

            // This is the example in all the examples.  
            // I'm not figuring out how to get to the correct users and how it know which Inbox.
            // there's no way to log in as my user?     
            inboxMessages = await graphClient
                .Users
                .Request()
                .Me
                .MailFolders
                .Inbox
                .Messages
                .Request()
                .Top(20)
                .GetAsync(); //this gives an error, I think because there's no ME
        }
        catch
        {
            //do some error handling
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't follow what you mean by "it only shows Delegate permissions" in the documentation. This isn't accurate, both [Delegated](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#delegated-permissions-10) and [Application](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#application-permissions-9) permissions are provided.

In order to read a user's mailbox you will need at least `Mail.Read` permission. If you need to write changes back to the mailbox however, you'll need `Mail.ReadWrite`. Since you're using Application scopes you will also need an Admin Consent before your application can access the mailbox.

Your Application ID (aka `clientId`) is generated when you register your Application.

When accessing a mailbox as an application, you will need to provide the user's `id` or `userPrincipalName` (typically `<user>@<domain>` or `<user>@<domain>.onmicrosoft.com`). You never use the `me` reference since there isn't a user within an Application only context.

To get a user's profile information from Microsoft Graph it would look like this (note that this requires the `User.Read.All` permission scope):

```cs
User myUser = await graphClient
    .Users["id or userPrincipalName"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

To return a user's inbox from their mailbox, it would look like this:

```cs
var messages = await graphClient
    .Users["id or userPrincipalName"]
    .Messages
    .Request()
    .Top(20)
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Marc, thank you so much for your help.   After reading all your comments to this and other posts, I finally came up with: inboxMessages = await graphClient.Users[userPrincipalName].MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().GetAsync();  This is working.  Maybe I don't have Users.Read.All permission scope and only to specific users?  I am going to add .Top(20) or else it may be too many.  Thank you.  Thank you.

Comment: Also, I realize now... you have to scroll past the Delegate permissions to see the Application permissions.  Thank you!

Comment: Do you think this is a good way to do the authentication?  It seems like there are so many different examples out there.  I like simple and this one seemed easy to me.

Comment: If you're operating as a daemon service, this is really the only option. App Scopes are a bit limited since they present a lot of risk (i.e. your app is effectively acting with admin rights for any scope it's given). If you _can_ operate within the context of a user then this is always preferable. It really depends on the scenario and if your app really needs access to every (or nearly every) user in the tenant.